# How to solve TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in Python while calculating sum of two numbers?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to take two values as parameters and return True if its value is equal to 10 and false if it isn't. The values are strictly int. Here is the code

```
    class Solution:
    def twomakes10(self, no1, no2):

        if sum(no1, no2) == 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    n1 = 9
    n2 = 1
    print(p.twomakes10(n1, n2))
```

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: The `sum()` function applies to *sequences* - lists, tuples, etc.  Simply adding two numbers is written `no1 + no2`.

Comment: The first parameter of `sum()` should be an iterable. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). You can simply do `if no1 + no2 == 10:`

Comment: There is no reason to use `if ... else` to transform a boolean into a boolean. Your 4-line definition for `twomakes10` can be replaced by the single line `return no1+no2 == 10`

Comment: To be clear: the question is "how do I add two numbers together in Python?" ?

Answer (score 1):

`sum` function, gets an iterable value as input, you can try:

```py
sum([no1,no2])
```

Comment: But why use `sum([no1,no2])` rather than `no1 + no2`?

Comment: You are right. I just pointed out the behavior of `sum`, in the case of generalizing the `make10` function, to receive unlimited inputs, using `sum` may be effective.

Answer (score 0):

`sum` is [expecting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) `iterable` .. so make it happy. See below

```
class Solution:

    def twomakes10(self, no1, no2):
        return sum([no1, no2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    n1 = 9
    n2 = 1
    print(p.twomakes10(n1, n2))
```

Comment: not anymore ...